# Cypress - How do I change URL for gitlab ci pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm very new to E2E test, cypress and gitlab ci. My idea is to run cypress test before each merge. But I don't know how to change the URL that I'm testing when I run a pipeline on gitlab. Let's say this is my first test:

```
it('Exibição de modal no clique do botão', () => {
        cy.visit('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
        cy.get('.inner-header-pt2 .header-buttons__cadastro').click();
        cy.get('.modal--login').should('be.visible');
})
```

For my local environment, I'm using the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000. How do I change to the right URL when I run this test on gitlab ci pipeline? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following

- Create multiple config files, each with different urls
- Target these in your plugins/index.js
- Create a command in your package.json for each environment
- Execute the corresponding command on your ci pipeline

Here is a detailed instruction:
https://ahmed-alsaab.medium.com/configuring-cypress-to-run-on-different-environments-7ae323bb3c86